# What DC Comic Book issue was the first to use the phrase "To the Bat-Cave"?

Tags: dc, batman, origins

I know it was used almost every week on the 1966 TV series, but I'd like to know if it was used in the comics, and if so, in what DC Comic Book issue was the phrase *To the Bat-Cave!* first uttered by Batman?

Comment: -1 because you inadvertently caused me to [learn what can't be unlearned](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=to+the+batcave)

Comment: @DVK. Well. That was enlightening. Sorry bro.

Comment: Also, nearly 100% of Google search results for that phrase seem to lead to the (unfortunate?) "[Return to the Batcave: The Misadventures of Adam and Burt (2003)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0321359/)"

Comment: "The Killing Joke" script by Alan Moore uses the phrase, BUT, as a storytelling thing, not as Batman's exclamation

Comment: "Batman: Gotham Knights #15" has the phrase, but as part of a replica by someone else (and not the same semantic meaning)

Comment: Unless it appears in some obscure early issue I haven't found yet, the exact catchphrase "To the Bat-cave!" seems to be an invention of the 1966 TV show. The closest I've found is "To the cave!"

Comment: @amaranth I was just interested in the comic books. :)